# sdn4-university example - authentication code

Tags: spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

i got the SDN4 - university example from here 
https://github.com/neo4j-examples/sdn4-university. We could run the project and test it. There is this authentication code in the angularjs front end code, but the back end api is not available for the same. Is it available somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It hasn't been implemented yet (though a PR is welcome)